# If not null then display * JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, null, calculated-columns

I am using reporting software Entrinsik Informer (only allows Javascript or HTML to accomplish what I want). I am pulling data from a U2 Unidata database. I have two columns side by side. One is prereq, which is from the database. The other is a calculated column I created which will display * if any field in prereq has data in it.  If it is empty then nothing will be displayed in the calculated column.

What it should do: Display an * for each course with a prerequisite
What it is doing: Displaying an * for every class

This is what I have, and it is displaying an * for every field even the ones that don't have any data.

My code:

```
var prereq=coursePrereq; //assigns a variable and loads it with data from the field in   database
var output="":
if(prereqs !=null) // if the field is not empty then
{
output='*';    // display an *
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

SOLUTION(9/17/13):
    var prereqs = courseSections4_crsifcrsprereqs;
    var output =" ";
    if (prereqs[0] !==null)
      {"*"}
    else
    {" "}

Answer (score 2):

Read this page, http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-2/ it gives a good explanation of how to check if a variable isn't a true value.

Pretty sure you could use

```
if( prereqs )
{
    output = '*';
}
```

And the above code would take into consideration whether or not the variable is undefined, null, or empty.

Comment: Here is what finally worked for me

Comment: var prereqs = courseSections4_crsifcrsprereqs;
    var output =" ";
    if (prereqs[0] !==null)
      {"*"}
    else
    {" "}

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know your software, I am guessing here

```
var prereq=coursePrereq;
var output= (prereq)?"*":"";
```

will set display to empty if prereq is 0, blank, null or undefined 
otherwise it will set it to "*"

If you have fields in prereq, we will need to see how you access them